# SharePoint 2010/2013 restful webservices for native iOS mobile development

Tags: ios, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm planning to develop a SharePoint 2010 native iOS solution with some basic features like login and fetch content. Are there any RESTFul web services exposed by SharePoint to work on, which lists the RESTFul web services that we can use?
Is there any initial steps that I need to follow to start up, provided the RESTFul web services are available?

Thanks
Sudheer

Comment: The below link provides the list of web services provided for SharePoint 2010 but it seems they are not useful for native mobile development if I'm not wrong. I want to create a request using NSMutableRequest & NSURLConnection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Dear all, I found some progress on this. Being a newbie on SharePoint it took sometime to check out where the web services are listed out. To check out the list of web services provided by the sharepoint server, just use the following URL. http://your_server_ip/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx . This list outs the available web services. But can someone give some idea of how the authentication happens since there is no web service available for authentication.